# WPF DataGridColumn Width="1*" when grid width is not set sometimes prevents columns filling

Tags: .net, wpf

I have two DataGrids inside dock panels:

```
<DataGrid FontSize="16" Margin="5" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGrid_CellStyle_CentreAlign}" RowHeight="40" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding Product}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding ProductDescription}" Width="1*"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty"  CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGrid_CellStyle_CentreRightAlign}">
               <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                      <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0:N0} {1}">
                           <Binding Path="Qty"/>
                           <Binding Path="QtyUOM"/>
                       </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          </DataGridTextColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGrid_CellStyle_CentreRightAlign}">
                 <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                       <MultiBinding   StringFormat="{}{0:N2} {1}">
                             <Binding Path="Weight"/>
                             <Binding Path="WeightUOM"/>
                       </MultiBinding>
                 </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

And the second:

```
 <DataGrid FontSize="16" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGrid_CellStyle_CentreAlign}" RowHeight="40" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Pallets}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pallet ID"  Binding="{Binding PalletId}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding Product}" Width="1*" />

   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

As you can see they are very similar and display correctly in the designer but when run this is the result:

[image: Grids]

As you can see the columns sizes on the second grid are wrong, the description column should expand to fill and the pallet column should auto size.

So far all I have worked out is that is something to do with the width of the DataGrid as by setting the width of the second DataGrid the columns display correctly (but the grid itself is no longer dynamic in size).

Comment: Seems to be set right to me.  Could it be that the panel it's in is causing the problem?  It might help to include the panels' xaml.

Comment: I think your on to something. I remove the DockPanels and put them in a Grid. Setting the grid column widths to * caused the problem in both datagrids but once set to a specific value the DataGrids behaive as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occures when you have a DataGrid in a dynamic width Grid column when you set your windows WindowState to Normal and set the Width and Height of your window in the Loaded event. Setting this in the constructor instead fixes the issue.